# Can't use clap because Sized is not implemented

Tags: rust, clap

When i try to print args, it does work, but accessing any parameter from the args does not work. Here is the function I am passing the clap arguments into.

The error it throws looks like this

no field `action` on type `T`rustcE0609
install.rs(4, 16): type parameter 'T' declared here

And I can't pass the Args directly because of dyn error.

```rust
use std::fmt::Debug;
use clap::Args;

pub fn execute<T: Args + ?Sized + Debug + Clone>(args: T) {
    // here i can't use the action struct parameter
    println!("Installing {:?}", args.action);
}
```

And here are the arguments

```rust
use clap::{
    Parser,
};

#[allow(non_camel_case_types)]
#[derive(clap::ValueEnum, Clone, Debug)]
pub enum Action {
    install,
    uninstall,
    switch
}

#[derive(Parser, Debug, Clone)]
#[clap(author="Atsukoro1", about="Cross-platform node.js version manager")]
pub struct Args {
    #[clap(
        value_enum,
        required=true,
    )]
    pub action: Action,

    #[clap(
        short, 
        long, 
        required_ifs(&[
            ("action", "install"), 
            ("action", "switch"),
            ("action", "uninstall")
        ])
    )]
    pub version: Option<String>,

    #[clap(
        short, 
        long, 
        required=false, 
        parse(from_os_str),
    )]
    pub nodepath: Option<std::path::PathBuf>,


    /// Specifies the path to the json config file
    /// 
    /// The default path is:
    ///     - Windows: %USERPROFILE%\.cnvm\config.json
    ///     - Linux: $HOME/.cnvm/config.json
    ///     - MacOS: $HOME/.cnvm/config.json
    /// 
    /// The config file is used to store all these things
    /// - The path to the node.js folder symlink
    #[clap(
        short, 
        long, 
        required=false, 
        parse(from_os_str)
    )]
    pub configpath: Option<std::path::PathBuf>,
}

impl Args {
    /// This function adds the default values to the arguments
    /// 
    /// It is currently not possible to do this with clap because of the
    /// &str/Strign problem when passing closure into default_value
    /// 
    /// TODO: Try to solve this in future
    pub fn parse_patched() -> Self {
        let mut args = Self::parse();

        if args.nodepath.is_none() {
            args.nodepath = Some(std::path::PathBuf::from(
                dirs::home_dir().unwrap().join(".nodejs")
            ));
        }

        if args.configpath.is_none() {
            args.configpath = Some(std::path::PathBuf::from(
                dirs::home_dir().unwrap().join(".cnvm/config.json")
            ));
        }

        args
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason for `execute` to be generic and not just accept your `Args` struct?